# MSpec -> How to verify that a method is called

Tags: c#, testing, bdd, assertions, mspec

I'm using MSpec in my Mobile Services application. I want to verify that a method on my custom logger is called when a param passed in is null. Is this possible?

#### code

```
if (someOrg == null || target == null) {
    AppUtils.LogInfo(">>>>> +++ Utils-GetAsNeededItems - Null input");
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) with MSpec.

```
// Mock something
Mock<ISomething> mock = new Mock<ISomething>();

ClassToTest sut = new ClassToTest();
sut.WorkMethod(mock.Object);

// Make sure the method TheMethodYouWantToCheck was called
mock.Verify(m => m.TheMethodYouWantToCheck());
```

You can also use the overload of `Verify` and make sure it was called once or at least x time, or at most x times etc.

```
mock.Verify(m => m.TheMethodYouWantToCheck(), Times.Once);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it when I get a chance.

Comment: FakeItEasy is also recommended. It has a very clean API and is functionally the same as Moq.

Comment: Is it possible to verify a static logger is called?